# Why does the array reads value not present?

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

Why is the console displaying arrayNew? I'm hoping a condition where if the array includes the elements 'a' and 'b' only then the console displays arrayNew.Can someone help me there?

```
var arrayNew = ['a'];
if(arrayNew.includes('b' && 'a'))
  console.log(arrayNew);
```

Comment: Have you tried to check what `'b' && 'd'` yields? None of the conditions check whether two strings are part of that array, but whether the **evaluated** value of AND is part of that array

Comment: Javascript isn't English. Your condition does not literally mean "arrayNew includes b and d"…

Answer (score 2):

`&&` evaluates as the left-hand value if that value is falsy and the right-hand value otherwise.

Since `'b'` is a true value, `'b' && 'd'` evaluates as `'d'`. The array **doesn't** include that so `arrayNew.includes('d')` is `false`.

Since `'d'` is a true value, `'d' && 'b'` evaluates as `'b'`.  The array **does** include that so `arrayNew.includes('b')` is `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Because `'b' && 'd' === 'd'`, the array doesn't include `'d'`, so the first `if` is false.

The second `if` is true because `'d' && 'b' === 'b'` and `'b'` is in the array.

If you want to know if it includes both values you must do

```
if (arr.includes('a') && arr.includes('b'))
```